# how to tar specific directories with specific names ( date month name )

Tags: linux, bash, tar, unzip

I have directory called **/var/tmp/all-results_dir** so in order to tar this directory we simply do that:

```
    tar -zcvf results_2014_10.tar.gz /var/tmp/all-results_dir
```

but when we want to tar the following specific directories only with **Jul** month 
Then how to run the tar in this case? ( or what need to  add to tar syntax ? )

**under /var/tmp/all-results_dir**

```
   drwxrwxrwx 3 eded  Unix_31 409 Jul  8 21:14 a87f2c43-096910
   drwxrwxrwx 3 dwc   Unix_31 409 Jul  8 21:19 ba5f59f-944df29
   drwxrwxrwx 3 nce   Unix_31 409 Jul  8 21:36 8b3b7e967740baa
   drwxrwxrwx 3 oke   Unix_31 409 Jul  8 21:37 433ee4bb4f57b72
   drwxrwxrwx 3 pli   Unix_31 409 Jul  8 21:39 57691d-7c09a23d
   drwxrwxrwx 3 nbd   Unix_31 409 Jul  8 21:48 4370de7b-93d887
   drwxrwxrwx 3 plo   Unix_31 409 Jul  8 21:51 686896a0-ed7532
   drwxrwxrwx 3 oke   Unix_31 409 Aug  8 21:37 4334f57b72efeff
   drwxrwxrwx 3 pli   Unix_31 409 Aug  8 21:39 523defefefef4cv
   drwxrwxrwx 3 nbd   Unix_31 409 Aug  8 21:48 437b-93d887bv45
   drwxrwxrwx 3 plo   Unix_31 409 Aug  8 21:51 680-ed7532dgvfv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using gnu `find` you can do:

```
find /var/tmp/all-results_dir -type f -newermt '2014-07-01' ! -newermt '2014-08-01' \
  -exec tar -rzf /var/TAR/results_2014_Jul.tar.gz {} +
```

- `-newermt '2014-07-01' ! -newermt '2014-08-01'` will find all files modified in the month of July 2014.
- `tar -rzf` will append files in the archive.

---

**Script `dotar.sh`:**

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -name 'f*' -newermt "2014-$1-01" ! -newermt "2014-$(($1+1))-01" \
   -exec tar -rzf /var/TAR/results_2014_$1.tar.gz {} +
```

**Call it as:**

```
./dotar.sh 7
```

Comment: can I tar like this --> tar -rzf /var/TAR/results_2014_Jul.tar.gz  ?

Comment: OK I will check that on my linux machine and will update soon - thx about your effort my friend

Comment: another question - how to be sure that the tar is do the job well and we can be sure about the tar backup because after tar I want to remove all the files that contain Jul

Comment: second I want to add your command in my bash script so can the date shuld be parameter for example -newermt '$fromdate' ! -newermt '$untildate'    can you update your solution according that ( in case is corecct )

Comment: To check tar file use: `tar tzf /var/TAR/results_2014_$1.tar.gz`. I have made it into a script above but please don't add new question from comments.